# Is there a way to determine if i'm working locally or on the internet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

My problem is originated from a force https function that one of our developers created
here is his code:

```
  var forcehttps = if(forcehttps && window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('http', 'https');
    }
```

problem with that is that we don't run currently https locally and I need a quick way to fix this without commenting his code locally.

The only thing I found out until now is using

```
location.hostname
```

so I can do something like that on my computer:

```
if(location.hostname === 'myHostName'){
//do the code above
}
```

which isn't good enough since we have multiple developers and each one uses a different hostname.

Is there is a quick and easy way to implement this?

Thx

Comment: There's no other way than to analyze hostname. Of course you can hide localhost ip behind any hostname but on the other hand you can do the same with any ip address. What I'm saying is that if your coleagues are not using standard localhost address then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Check out this for suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162457/how-to-check-with-javascript-if-connection-is-local-host