# How to only read Google maps API key in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a React application that uses Google maps. I've been working on it in development mode only and would like to add the API key now when I push it to production.

I'm loading the Google Maps script like the code below and it seems to work, but I would like to only read from my .env and use the API key in production, not when I develop locally on http://localhost:3000/, etc. Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do this?

```
if (!scriptElementExists) {
                // Create a new script tag
                const scriptElement = createScriptElement(
                    'google-maps',
                    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}&callback=${googleMapsData.scriptCallbackName}`
                );

                // Append the script to the document
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
            }
```

My .env

```
# Google Maps Api Key
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY={{API_KEY}}
```

Thanks beforehand!

And please ask if I've made myself clear.

Comment: The most recent answer (2020) from @Holtwick at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162457/how-to-check-with-javascript-if-connection-is-local-host looks useful and seems to cover the most common cases at the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Create React App you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`.
It is set automatically to `development` or `production`.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables